# Will a new 16.04 installation overwrite a failed 15.10 upgrade?

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 15.10, 16.04

I attempted to upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 last night - it appeared to hit a point in installation where it started to hang then froze/failed overnight. I bought the laptop originally with Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual boot. Before upgrading I backed up my user's /home directory. Now on boot Ubuntu won't mount and just freezes immediately.

Having never done an install on my own (rather previously using vm's), can I install 16.04 from a jump drive and have it overwrite the failed 15.10 instance then just restore my backed up directory? Or will doing so install a fresh 16.04 instance with its own partition?

I apologize in advance if there are many other 16.04 upgrade questions - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get to choose between "use entire disk" and "do something else". You want to do "something else" and then choose the current 15.10 partition to format and install 16.04 on. Also, the current swap partition can be used again as a swap partition. Doublecheck that the partition settings are correct before you press "Install".

Comment: Great thank you - I'll give that a shot tonight and update here hopefully after restoring my other directory.

Comment: This did work after booting from live usb - however I think something was corrupted as I couldn't repair the installation, rather freshly installing a fresh 16.04. Back to the purple and orange.

Answer (score 0):

If your home directory is not corrupted, you can reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from a bootable medium such as a LiveUSB or DVD-ROM. You will be given the option to reinstall your OS, and keeping your Home folder files.